# AttributeError: module 'yahoo_finance' has no attribute 'download'

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

```
import yahoo_finance as yfinance
raw_data = yfinance.download (tickers = "^GSPC ^FTSE ^N225 ^GDAXI", #The time 
 #series we are interested in - (in our case, these are the S&P, FTSE, NIKKEI and DAX)
start = "1994-01-07", #The starting date of our data set
end = "2019-09-27", #The ending date of our data set (at the time of 
                              # upload, this is the current date)
interval = "1d", #The distance in time between two recorded observations. 
#Since we're using daily closing prices, we set it equal 
#to "1d", which indicates 1 day. 
group_by = 'ticker', #The way we want to group the scraped data. Usually we 
#want it to be "ticker", so that we have all the 
#information about a time series in 1 variable.
auto_adjust = True, #Automatically adjuss the closing prices for each 
# period. 
treads = True) #Whether to use threads for mass downloading.
```

I am doing a Udemy course on Time series. And trying to access yahoo finance. But error is as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-817ad07416bf> in <module>
      1 # Using the .download() method to get our data
      2 
----> 3 raw_data = yfinance.download (tickers = "^GSPC ^FTSE ^N225 ^GDAXI", #The time series we are 
interested in - (in our case, these are the S&P, FTSE, NIKKEI and DAX)
      4                               start = "1994-01-07", #The starting date of our data set
      5                               end = "2019-09-27", #The ending date of our data set (at the 
 time of upload, this is the current date)

 AttributeError: module 'yahoo_finance' has no attribute 'download'
```

Please help.

Comment: I can not find `download` method in `yahoo_finance` [docs](https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/). Are you sure `download` method is there?

Comment: I resolved this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that yahoo-finance has been depracated by pandas. The alternative is either fix-yahoo-finance or using y-finance.

Anaconda prompt, type:

```
 python -m pip install yfinance
 pip install fix-yahoo-finance
```

Then in Anconda prompt/Pycharmn/Jupyter/Spyder etc type:

```
 import yfinance
```

Now you can proceed as before. yfinance has download option

Comment: you can also use [`pandas_datareader`](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)